# Why am I getting a UnicodeDecodeError in Python's JSON encoding?

Tags: python, json

I am using Solr 3.3 to index stuff from my database. I compose the JSON content in Python. I manage to **upload 2126 records which add up to 523246 chars (approx 511kb)**. But when I try 2027 records, Python gives me the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "D:\Technovia\db_indexer\solr_update.py", line 69, in upload_service_details
    request_string.append(param_list)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\json\__init__.py", line 238, in dumps
    **kw).encode(obj)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\json\encoder.py", line 203, in encode
    chunks = list(chunks)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\json\encoder.py", line 425, in _iterencode
    for chunk in _iterencode_list(o, _current_indent_level):
  File "C:\Python27\lib\json\encoder.py", line 326, in _iterencode_list
    for chunk in chunks:
  File "C:\Python27\lib\json\encoder.py", line 384, in _iterencode_dict
    yield _encoder(value)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0x96 in position 68: invalid start byte
```

Ouch. Is 512kb worth of bytes a fundamental limit? Is there any high-volume alternative to the existing JSON module?

---

**Update**: its a fault of some data as trying to encode *biz_list[2126:]* causes an immediate error. Here is the offending piece:

> '2nd Floor, Gurumadhavendra Towers,\nKadavanthra Road, Kaloor,\nCochin **\x96** 682 017'

How can I configure it so that it can be encodable into JSON?

---

**Update 2**: The answer worked as expected: the data came from a MySQL table encoded in "latin-1-swedish-ci". I saw significance in a random number. Sorry for spontaneously channeling the spirit of a headline writer when diagnosing the fault.

Comment: This has nothing to do with the size of your json.

Comment: Did you read the error? You have a byte that isn't valid `utf-8` in your data. This has nothing to do with the size. Show us the code and look at the data in that particular field.

Comment: For a trivial counterexample, `json.dumps({"megastring": "-" * 1000000})` produces a one megabyte JSON object.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Simple, just don't use utf-8 encoding if your data is not in utf-8

```
>>> json.loads('["\x96"]')
....
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0x96 in position 0: invalid start byte

>>> json.loads('["\x96"]', encoding="latin-1")
[u'\x96']
```

> **json.loads**
>
> If `s` is a `str` instance and is encoded with an ASCII based
>   encoding other than utf-8 (e.g. latin-1) then an appropriate
>   `encoding` name must be specified. Encodings that are not ASCII
>   based (such as UCS-2) are not allowed and should be decoded to
>   `unicode` first.

**Edit**: To get proper unicode value of "\x96" use "cp1252" as Eli Collins mentioned

```
>>> json.loads('["\x96"]', encoding="cp1252")
[u'\u2013']
```

Comment: Just to nitpick - latin-1 doesn't define a character for \x96, though the python codec will willingly decode it (but as a raw byte value, not a particular character). The correct codec is probably cp1252 (microsoft's extension of latin-1), which defines byte \x96 as unicode char 2012 (en-dash). Pretty much any ascii-looking encoding with a bunch of \x90-\x9F chars is likely to be cp1252, as windows systems generate these characters (smart quotes, etc) a lot.

Comment: @Eli, Thank you, updated the post. I got 2013 on my ubuntu though.

Comment: Doh. 2013 is what my console prints too. I need some coffee :)