# Extract data as JSON in HTML page from nested list

Tags: python, json, beautifulsoup

My data is to find here: https://paste2.org/72LmCn2P

How is it possible to extract data from this kind of JSON?

[image]

I can see from the View in Firefox, that Firefox can transform this list to a working JSON format. Snippet Code:

```
    with urllib.request.urlopen("url") as url:
        soup = BeautifulSoup(url, "html.parser")
        output_file.write(str(json.loads(soup.get_text())))
```

How Can I transform this kind of data in a useful transformed data?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like a *JSON respons*e you are getting - that means that you don't need an HTML parser to parse it - load it with [`json.load()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#json.load) directly:

```
import json

with urllib.request.urlopen("url") as response:
    data = json.load(response)
    print(data)
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I get the Error: `UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xf6 in position 68: invalid start byte`

Comment: @madik_atma ah, you need to specify the encoding - this might be relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7146199/771848.

Comment: In your code you have use .load, in the link he explained it for .loads? You mean .load accept the keyword encoding?

Comment: @madik_atma you can do `json.loads(response.read(), encoding="your_encoding")`.

Comment: Its work now under his flow: `data = json.loads(response.read().decode('utf-8', 'ignore')) output_json.write(str(data))` . But its still not in the useful formation. How can I extract or load the data from this response data? Thank you!